# Does Git have any native way to canonicalize (resolve) symlinks, like readlink -f?

Tags: git

readlink -f, according to its man page:

"canonicalize[s] by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist"

I want an equivalent of "readlink -f" for Git.  In other words, a way to follow every symlink in a path at a given commit in a repository, ending up with a canonical version of the path.

I've written my own function that does this (below), but I would like to know whether Git has native functionality that does the same thing.  And, if it doesn't, maybe it would be worth considering including equivalent functionality in a new release of Git.  Thanks.

```
SYMLINK_FILE_TYPE_OCTAL="12"
MAX_SYMLINK_COUNT=10

git-is-symlink() {
  local commit="$1"
  local dir="$2"
  local base="$3"
  git ls-tree "${commit}:$dir" "$base" | grep -q -P "^$SYMLINK_FILE_TYPE_OCTAL"
}

git-get-symlink-target() {
  local commit="$1"
  local dir="$2"
  local base="$3"

  if test -z "$dir"; then
    local path="$base"
  else
    local path="$dir/$base"
  fi
  git cat-file blob "$commit:$path"
}

git-resolve-path-recursive() {
  local commit="$1"
  local resolved_prefix="$2"
  local segment_to_be_resolved="$3"
  local unresolved_suffix="$4"
  local symlink_count="$5"

  if test -z "$segment_to_be_resolved" && test -z "$unresolved_suffix"; then
    echo "$resolved_prefix"
    return
  fi

  if test "$symlink_count" -gt "$MAX_SYMLINK_COUNT"; then
    echo "Exceeded symlink count of $MAX_SYMLINK_COUNT on '$prefix' '$segment_to_be_resolved'" >&2
    exit 1
  fi

  if test -n "$segment_to_be_resolved" && git-is-symlink "$commit" "$resolved_prefix" "$segment_to_be_resolved"; then
    local symlink_target="$(git-get-symlink-target "$commit" "$resolved_prefix" "$segment_to_be_resolved")"
    git-resolve-path-recursive "$commit" "$resolved_prefix" "$symlink_target" "$unresolved_suffix" $((++symlink_count))
  else
    if test -z "$resolved_prefix"; then
      local new_resolved_prefix="$segment_to_be_resolved"
    else
      local new_resolved_prefix="$resolved_prefix/$segment_to_be_resolved"
    fi
    local new_segment_to_be_resolved="$(echo "$unresolved_suffix" | cut -d / -f 1)"
    local new_unresolved_suffix="$(echo "$unresolved_suffix" | cut -s -d / -f 2-)"
    git-resolve-path-recursive "$commit" "$new_resolved_prefix" "$new_segment_to_be_resolved" "$new_unresolved_suffix" 0
  fi
}

## Main entry point
## USAGE: git-resolve-path COMMIT PATH
git-resolve-path() {
  local commit="$1"
  local path="$2"
  git-resolve-path-recursive "$commit" "" "" "$path" 0
}
```

Example usage:

```
> mkdir -p targetdir
> ln -s targetdir linkdir
> touch targetdir/targetfile
> ln -s targetfile targetdir/linkfile
> git add targetdir linkdir targetdir/targetfile targetdir/linkfile
> git commit -m "Add files"
> git-resolve-path HEAD linkdir/linkfile
targetdir/targetfile
```